# Convert different salary types (per year, per month etc) to monthly in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have scraped some salaries of jobs. The data is in a few formats (eg, per month, per year, per day). I want to standardize everything to a month.

```
jobs_df['salary']
7       7000 -  8000 a month
9       50000 - 80000 a year
5       80000 - 90000 a year
5       25000 - 28000 a year
4            450 - 600 a day
5               32925 a year
9               48300 a year
```

My plan is to `jobs_df['salary'].str.split('-)` and take the mean of the salaries. However, the presence of text like 'a month', 'a year', 'a day' is tripping me up. What's a pythonic way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) or [`extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for get `numeric`, convert to `floats` and last get `mean`:

```
jobs_df['new'] = pd.DataFrame(jobs_df['salary'].str.findall('(\d+)').values.tolist(),
                              index=jobs_df.index).astype(float).mean(1)
print (jobs_df)
                    salary      new
0     7000 -  8000 a month   7500.0
1     50000 - 80000 a year  65000.0
2     80000 - 90000 a year  85000.0
3     25000 - 28000 a year  26500.0
4          450 - 600 a day    525.0
5             32925 a year  32925.0
6             48300 a year  48300.0
```

Or:

```
jobs_df['new'] = jobs_df['salary'].str.extractall('(\d+)')[0].unstack().astype(float).mean(1)
print (jobs_df)
                    salary      new
0     7000 -  8000 a month   7500.0
1     50000 - 80000 a year  65000.0
2     80000 - 90000 a year  85000.0
3     25000 - 28000 a year  26500.0
4          450 - 600 a day    525.0
5             32925 a year  32925.0
6             48300 a year  48300.0
```

EDIT:

```
m1 = jobs_df['salary'].str.contains('month')
m2 = jobs_df['salary'].str.contains('day')
jobs_df['fin'] =np.select([m1, m2], 
                          [jobs_df['new'] * 12,jobs_df['new'] * 365], default=jobs_df['new'])
print (jobs_df)
                    salary      new       fin
0     7000 -  8000 a month   7500.0   90000.0
1     50000 - 80000 a year  65000.0   65000.0
2     80000 - 90000 a year  85000.0   85000.0
3     25000 - 28000 a year  26500.0   26500.0
4          450 - 600 a day    525.0  191625.0
5             32925 a year  32925.0   32925.0
6             48300 a year  48300.0   48300.0
```

Comment: This is right but does not account for salary / day, year, month. Jezrael could probably solve that in a very nice manner too adding a multiplier. :) +1

Comment: @AntonvBR How should I approach this?
 `if 'month' in df['salary'] then df['new'] * 12` is this a good approach?

Comment: @AntonvBR - Thanks

Comment: @JamesSoh - Also need multiple `df['new'] * 365` for days?